# How to fix a exponential regression to positively skewed data?

Tags: r, regression, exponential

[file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yP86rpwpSoXD9qC0sMCg9me84xOm-3UV/view?usp=sharing)i am trying to explore exponential regression for predicting #calls_to_be_made(DV) for given #sales_potential(IDV) of customers.The data is positively skewed. is it better to try exponential regression for this case.? if so how to proceed? if not why? Need some more ideas.

I have to performed linear regression to predict #calls_to_be_made(DV) for given #sales_potential(IDV) of customers.The data is positively skewed. I have eliminated zero values and i have log10 transformed both the variables to get near normal distribution. it gave an rsqr value of 55%.

The expected result is how to perform exponential regression and also need clarity of thought on which model (technique) is good to prefer for my particular problem.?

```
#importdata
file1<-read.xlsx("wx2.xlsx",sheetName = "Sheet1",header = T)
str(file1)
#file1$Potential.18.19<-round(file1$Potential.18.19,digits = 0)
data1<-file1
data1$Sales_to_be_made <- log10(data1$Sales_to_be_made)
data1$calls_to_be_made <- log10(data1$calls_to_be_made)
dput(data1)
```

Comment: Related: [Fitting an exponential model to data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11947/fitting-an-exponential-model-to-data) and [Exponential regression in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475326/exponential-regression-in-r)

Comment: Would you please post a link to the data?

Comment: posted link for file.